# Put inline HTML into variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contentplaceholder

Is there a way to put an inline HTML in a view into variable? Something like this:

```
<% t = content_to_var do %>
   <h1>The title</h1>
<% end %>

<% my_var = content_to_var do %>
   <p>Watch this fine results:</p>
   <table>
   <tr><td>Value 1.1</td><td>Value 1.2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value 2.1</td><td>Value 2.2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value 3.1</td><td>Value 3.2</td></tr>
   </table>
<% end %>

<%= render 'partial', { title: t, contents: my_var }
```

Please be aware that I know about absence of function named exactly "content_to_var". It is mentioned only for example.

I know about content_for and yield, but want to do the same through locals.

I do not like an idea to do

```
my_var = '<table><tr><td>Value 1.1</td><td>Value 1.2</td></tr></table>'.html_safe
```

It looks ugly.

Comment: Why do you want to pass those variables to a partial? The idea of views (and partials) is that it contains mainly static HTML (or XML, or whatever) and you add variables inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old versions of Rails you can do

```
<% t = capture do %>
  <h1>The title</h1>
<% end %>
```

Don't know about newer versions

Comment: In my opinion that is not so clean. Don't know the whole situation for you. But I would have moved the capturing to the partial instead (and not using capture there), and use locals/instance variables to solve it. Or perhaps made helper method(s) instead of the partial, and used them in the main loop in your rhtml.

Comment: I managed do the task without any partials. Have defined an array, where each string was formed by capture, then used "each". Thanks to any who responded - it helped me to choose the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just render partials? That's what they are made for.

You could do something like:

```
<% t = render :partial => 'title', :title => 'The title' %>
<% my_var = render :partial => 'values', :values => @values %>

<% render :partial => {title: t, contents: my_var } %>
```

And for completeness, your `_title.html.erb` would look like

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to render the same partial in a loop taking values from an array.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say with that comment. Do you want to see an example where a partial is rendered in a loop?